# Why will current wireless microphone frequency become illegal in Australia?

Tags: wireless-networking, microphone

I came across this [cnet article](http://www.cnet.com.au/australian-wireless-microphone-frequencies-become-illegal-in-2015-339345508.htm) this morning.

But can not understand why change in frequency means I need to replace my old wireless transmitters. Would it be interfering in the transmission for other devices?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A full explanation would be way to long so here is a brief:*

Wireless audio equipment is currently permitted to operate in the vacant spectrum between UHF television services (520-820 MHz)

In Australia we're making the switch from analog television signals to digital signals and the Australian Communications and Media Authority wants to do a "Restack" of frequencies as part of this; your wireless mic isn't the only thing in the cross hairs.

Currently analog and digital run on the same 520-820 MHz spectrum.

[image: Australia restack]

Following the switch-over from analog to digital television, the range 694-820 MHz will be cleared

520-694 MHz will continue to be used by television, and it is expected that wireless audio equipment will continue to operate in this range under similar arrangements to the current LIPD licence

Telstra has already [announced](http://exchange.telstra.com.au/2013/05/15/banding-together-to-get-devices-for-700mhz/) the purchase of the 700 MHz frequency to use as a 4G network as it will work better in rural areas

---

### TL;DR

Everything that currently resides in the 694-820 MHz spectrum will be moved. Wireless mics and headphones just happen to be in that range.